# Run new terminal with bash running command

Tags: bash, terminal

If I want to run a command, say `ranger`, in a new termite terminal, I can use

`termite -e "ranger"`

and, if I want to run `ranger` inside a bash sub-instance, I can use

`bash --init-file <(echo ranger)`

so what is it that I am doing wrong when I run

`termite -e "bash --init-file <(echo ranger)"`

My hope is to be able to open a terminal running ranger so that quitting ranger takes me back to bash.

Comment: I don't have termite around to check, but does `termite -e 'ranger; bash'` work?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: try either `termite -e sh -c 'ranger; bash'` or `termite -x sh -c 'ranger; bash'` (the `-e` flag should work in xterm-like terminal emulators; the `-x` in gnome-terminal & such, which had badly implemented the `-e` switch)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have termite either, but with Terminator, using `ranger; exec bash` works. But then, so does `ranger; bash` so it's not a good test.  Anyhow, it's worth a try:

```sh
termite -e 'ranger; exec bash'
```